# Flash: bitmap inaccuracy

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I load a bitmap to the stage, it's a GIF and set to lossless compression. I have ensured its coordinates are integers and have not allowed smoothing (smoothing somewhat fixes the issue but reduces quality of the image).

The problem is the image appears to shift one pixel to the left and add that pixel on to the right side meaning one side has no border and the other a double border.

The original bitmap does not have this issue, and there is no transparency .etc in the image.

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried converting it to jpg before importing it to Flash? Flash converts everything to jpeg before outputing images.

Comment: @Kodiak Are you sure? I don't think it does as it allows you to choose between jpeg compression and lossless PNG/GIF compression in the bitmap properties. Seems silly that you are forced to compress an image if you don't want to, especially if it is sub 255 colours.

Comment: Can you some code? also perhaps an image of the problem your having?

Comment: @Taurayi it is not a code problem the image is imported directly onto the stage through the IDE

Comment: @George then why the actionscript-3 and actionscript tabs? also the air and adobe-air tags? It seems like it should be flash and flash-x(x being cs3, cs4 etc).

Comment: @Taurayi because this is what I am compiling to.

Answer (score 0):

I would try the jpeg thing - honestly gif's act funny in flash more often than not for me so I tend to only use jpeg's now.

Also, it seems simple, but check to ensure the gif isn't being scaled - quality often suffers whenever a raster image is scaled in flash for me too.

Comment: I cannot afford to use a jpeg because this is for a mobile app and is being compiled for air for ios... a lossless jpeg is much greater filesize and even a lossy one is bigger than my gif. Need to keep size down to a minimum.

Comment: in that case, are you scaling the gif?

Comment: nope it doesn't change at all. 100% 100% on both scale values and nothing changes the gif later in the application.